# How to split bash script into commands?

Tags: bash, parsing

For example this bash script i can split by EOL to commands:

```
echo "1"
pwd
cd ../
```

But how to split more complex bash scripts like below?

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 file ..."
  exit 1
fi

echo "$0 counts the lines of code" 
l=0; n=0; s=0
for f in $*
do
    l=`wc -l $f | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
    echo "$f: $l"
        n=$[ $n + 1 ]
        s=$[ $s + $l ]
done

echo "$n files in total, with $s lines in total"
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: In addition, take a look at `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) in `man bash`. Much will depend on your desired output, but `IFS` is a good place for you to start.

Comment: @david: the shell does not use the contents of $IFS to *parse* commands. It's used during word-splitting, which is part of parameter substitution, but the shell command is initially split into words by considering whitespace and shell metacharacters.

Comment: I guess I should have been little more clear, I was considering redirection within either a command substitution to read the file or by feeding a while loop with the redirection. In that case, `IFS` would come into play in the word splitting of the redirected input. Either creating an indexed array of lines with, e.g. `IFS=$'\n'; a=( $(<file) )` or `while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do #additional parsing; done <file` The further parsing could be done with further refinements to `IFS`. Those were just starting thoughts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this is bad starting point. A good starting point will be a grammar.

Comment: Yes and no. While you are correct there is no guarantee that a line has much meaning, *chunking* the input into blocks you can check for continuations or follow-ons from *pipes* or *compound commands* that do not require continuations is one way to start. If you have a better approach from a grammar standpoint, I look forward to reviewing your answer.